# Jsch rm thread synchro on android

Tags: android, multithreading, ssh, jsch

I'm working on sftp with android. I use `JSch` to establish the channel between the server an the device but I have a problem :

First the user have to choose a list of file to download and for each file an `intentService` is created to download the file. Then I make a md5 check to know if the download is ok and finally if the integrity is ok I have to delete the file from the server.

The main problem is that I have an error : `SftpException 4:`  without description, I think the service is closed when I try to delete the file from the server, so the channel is closed to and the file cannot be found.

I have other activity monitoring all the downloads + global progression. But I can't delete the file in this one because Network on `MainThread`... So I think I can create the `SftpChannel` on a separate thread and give it to the activity. But how can I do it ? I know that `BroadcastIntents` cannot send these types of data...

So to resume :

`DownloadSFTPService => IntentService : open the SftpChannel` and download the file, send data to RunningDownloadsActivity for the progression.

```
RunningDownloadsActivity => ListActivity : Monitor all the downloads + global receiving via BrodcastIntent updates from DownloadSftpService.
```

DownloadSftpService :

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    //initializations

    //Création de la session avec le serveur
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(loginFtp, ipServer, GlobalEnum.DOWNLOAD.PORT);
        if(session == null)
        {
            Log.e("SSHError","Impossible d'instancier la session");
        }
        else
        {

            //Configuration de la connexion par mot de passe plutot que certificat
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("PreferredAuthentifications", "password");
            session.setConfig(config);

            //Récupération du mot de passe dans les préférences et ouverture de session avec le serveur
            session.setPassword(passwordFtp);
            session.connect();

            //Configuration du canal en mode sFTP et ouverture
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.connect();

            //Initialisation de la notification
            initialiseNotif();

            //Lancement du téléchargement des fichiers
            downloadFiles();

            //Clôture de la connexion
            sftpChannel.disconnect();

        }
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        Log.e("JschException", e.toString());
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        Log.e("SftpException", e.toString());
    }

}

    private void downloadFiles() throws SftpException
{
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> file;

    //Pour chaque fichier
    for( String tempFileName : downloadList)
    {           
        if(fileExisting(tempFileName)) {
            //Récupération des infos fichier
            file = sftpChannel.ls(tempFileName);
            currentFileSize = file.get(0).getAttrs().getSize();
            currentFileName = file.get(0).getFilename();

            broadcastIntentRD.putExtra(GlobalEnum.DOWNLOAD.FILE_NAME, currentFileName);
            broadcastIntentRD.putExtra(GlobalEnum.DOWNLOAD.FILE_SIZE, currentFileSize);

            //Lancement du téléchargement 

            int lastDot = tempFileName.lastIndexOf(".");
            String baseFileName = null;
            if(tempFileName.endsWith("tar.gz"))
            {
                String temp = tempFileName.substring(0, lastDot);
                baseFileName = temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf("."));
            } else {
                baseFileName = tempFileName.substring(0, lastDot );
            }

            try {
                sftpChannel.get(baseFileName + ".md5", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + vamsillaPath + "/" + baseFileName + ".md5");
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                Log.v("Sftp", "md5 introuvable pour : " + currentFileName);
            }
            sftpChannel.get(file.get(0).getFilename(), Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + vamsillaPath + "/" + file.get(0).getFilename(),this);
        }

    }
```

RunningDownloadsActivity :

```
public class DownloadReceiverRD extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //BLABLA for notification and progressbar update

                    if(progress == fileSize){

                        //BLABLA for notification and progressbar closing


                        md5Sum(fileName);
                    }
                }
      private void md5Sum(String currentFileName) {
        VamsillaTools tools = new VamsillaTools(getApplicationContext());

        //Ouverture de la base de stockage des fichiers

        //Insertion du résultat dans la BDD
        int result = tools.checkMD5(currentFileName);
        db.insertFile(currentFileName, result);
        switch(result) {
            case -1 : Log.v("MD5", "Problème lors de la comparaison md5 : " + currentFileName); break;
            case 0 : Log.v("MD5", "Comparaison md5 fausse : " + currentFileName); break;
            case 1 : Log.v("MD5", "Succès de la comparaison md5 pour : " + currentFileName);

    /********
      SUPRESS THE FILE HERE WOULD BE PERFECT !!! 
    *********/

   break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please excuse my english, I'm french, and you know how good we are for foreign languages...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe late, but if it can help someone...
 I finally juste made a class inheriting from Thread doing network + deleting the file, when we stop searching for difficult ways, it's pretty simple :)